# How to add custom TUser and TRole into services.AddIdentity in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have error in next code in

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

    services.AddIdentity<ApsUser, ApsRole>(option =>
        {
            option.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })
```

> GenericArguments[0], 'project.Core.Users.ApsUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.

My class

```
public class ApsUser : IdentityUser<int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>, IEntity
{
    public UserState State { get; set; }

    #region IEntityLogFields



    #endregion

}

public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>, IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    #region IEntityLogFields



    #endregion

}
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: Could you show the implementations of ApsRole and ApsUser?

Comment: I edited the first message

Comment: What is the reason behind `ApsUser` inheriting from `IdentityUser<int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>, IEntity`? Is `ApsUser : IdentityUser` not enough?

Comment: Could you just inherit like `ApsUser : IdentityUser` and `services.AddIdentity<ApsUser, IdentityRole>(option =>  {           option.Password.RequiredLength = 6; })` try again? Do not use `ApsRole` just for the sake of testing.

Comment: And necessarily IdentityUser<int>

Comment: I cant use ApsUser : IdentityUser because i have DBContext inheritув from namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Base class for the Entity Framework database context used for identity.
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   TUser:
    //     The type of the user objects.
    public class IdentityDbContext<TUser> : IdentityDbContext<TUser, IdentityRole, string> where TUser : IdentityUser

Comment: DbContext should inherit from IdentityDbContext, if you use Identity Core and EF. For example, `YourDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApsUser>`

Comment: I try to use if ApsUser: IdentityUser I have not error

Comment: Does it solve the problem or do you still have an issue?

Comment: yes there is, the default value is not satisfied. We need int

Comment: It's discussed here: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1082#issuecomment-273514725

Answer (score -1):

Temporary i made this

1. user and role

   `public class ApsUser : IdentityUser<int>, IEntity`

   public class ApsRole : IdentityRole, IEntityLog
2. startup.cs

   services.AddIdentity(option =>
           {
               option.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
               option.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
               option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
               option.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
               option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

   ```
       })
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApContext, int>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
   ```

Comment: .net core 2.2, i can not find .AddEntityFrameworkStores with two parameters.